# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.input_lib' has no attribute 'DistributedDatasetInterface'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I'm trying to run this code for a people counting algorithm.

```
model = build_model()

epoch = 50

print("total epoch ", epoch)

model.fit(x=train_dataset, shuffle=True, epochs=epoch)
save_model(model, MODEL_PATH, MODEL_JSON_PATH)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

After executing the command, I get this error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-98c7633734a8> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 print("total epoch ", epoch)
      6 
----> 7 model.fit(x=train_dataset, shuffle=True, epochs=epoch)
      8 save_model(model, MODEL_PATH, MODEL_JSON_PATH)
      9 sys.stdout.flush()

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _is_distributed_dataset(ds)
   1694 
   1695 def _is_distributed_dataset(ds):
-> 1696   return isinstance(ds, input_lib.DistributedDatasetInterface)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.input_lib' has no attribute 'DistributedDatasetInterface'
```

Answer (score 1):

> **tensorflow/python/keras code is a legacy copy of Keras since the TensorFlow v2.7 release, and will be deleted in the v2.12 release.**

> Please remove any import of `tensorflow.python.keras` and use the public API with

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf; tf.keras
```

> *I tried to execute the mentioned code on tensorflow v2.13 by using below imports and it was executed without any issues.*

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid
```

git link : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61215#issuecomment-1628600138